# MySQL - Join 2 Tables and Group Values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've gotten some good help on here with some tricky stuff like this, so thought I'd have you guys take a look and see if this is even possible.

I have two tables in MySQL ..  company and resources ...

companies can have multiple resources .. so ...

```
company
--------
companyId (primary/auto inc)
companyName

resources
---------
resourceId (primary/auto inc)
companyId
resourceName
```

I'd like to query the two tables and group it so the results look like this ...

Example...

```
Company Name
 ResourceName1
 ResourceName2
 ResourceName3
Company Name
 Resource Name4
 Resource Name5
Company Name3
 Resource Name6
```

etc..

Hope that makes sense.. any help is much appreciated.

**Update**

Ok to help clarify this a little better ...

I need to pull up every company in the company table, and then using that companyId, use that to pull every resource in the resource table with that same companyId ...

So the list would look like this ...

```
Bob's Plumbing (aka Company name)
  Bob the Plumber (has CompanyId of Bob's Plumbing)
  Bob's Assistant (has CompanyId of Bob's Plumbing)
Joe's Roofing (aka Company name)
  Joe the Roofer (has CompanyId of Joe's Roofing)
```

etc.. etc...

Hope that clears up some of the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could suggets this query -

**EDITed**

```
SELECT
  c.companyName,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(r.resourceName, ' ', r.resourceFirstname, ' ', r.resourceLastname) SEPARATOR '\r\n')
FROM
  company c
JOIN
  resources r
    ON c.companyId = r.companyId
GROUP BY
  c.companyId;
```

Note, that company name and its resources will be in one row.

Comment: Can you possibly tell me how to use this with more than one field from the resource tables (ie r.resourceFirstname r.resourceLastname)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I have modified query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select companyName,GROUP_CONCAT(resourceName) from company,resources where company.companyId=resources.companyId;
```