# Join 2 tables and group values result shows differently from what I expected

Tags: mysql, join

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923038/mysql-join-2-tables-and-group-values) that can finally help with my issue but turns out, it is not working for my case.

If I did not include GROUP BY in my query, I will get this :

```
Form Name : Account Registration  
User Details : 11/27/1987         
Form Name : Account Registration  
User Details : test1@gmail.com    
Form Name : Account Registration  
User Details : username_test      
Form Name : Account Registration  
User Details : 11/27/1999         
Form Name : Account Registration  
User Details : +6582734752        
Form Name : Account Registration  
User Details : Teamname1          
Form Name : Account Registration  
User Details : Team1              
Form Name : Account Registration  
User Details : Teamname2          
Form Name : Account Registration  
User Details : Team2              
Form Name : Event Registration
User Details : +862934829103      
Form Name : Event Registration
User Details : testing@test.com   
Form Name : Christmas Event Registration
User Details : Member1            
Form Name : Christmas Event Registration
User Details : Member2            
Form Name : Christmas Event Registration
User Details : Member3            
Form Name : Christmas Event Registration
User Details : Member4            
Form Name : Christmas Event Registration
User Details : TeamAlpha          
Form Name : Christmas Event Registration
User Details : teamalpha@gmail.com
```

But if I include GROUP BY in my query, I get this :

```
Form Name : Account Registration  
User Details : 11/27/1987  
Form Name : Christmas Event Registration
User Details : Member1
Form Name : Event Registration
User Details : +862934829103
```

This is what I want to achieve :

```
Form Name : Account Registration
  User Details : 11/27/1987, test1@gmail.com, username_test
  User Details : .....
  User Details : .....
Form Name : Event Registration
  User Details : 11/27/1999, +6582734752
  User Details : .....
  User Details : .....
Form Name : Christmas Event Registration
  User Details : Member1, Member2, Member3, Member4,TeamAlpha, teamalpha@gmail.com
  User Details : .....
  User Details : .....
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  `form_id` INTEGER,
  `form_name` VARCHAR(28)
);

INSERT INTO Table1
  (`form_id`, `form_name`)
VALUES
  ('3', 'Account Registration'),
  ('5', 'Event Registration'),
  ('6', 'Christmas Event Registration');

CREATE TABLE Table2 (
  `form_id` INTEGER,
  `submission_id` INTEGER,
  `value` VARCHAR(19)
);

INSERT INTO Table2
  (`form_id`, `submission_id`, `value`)
VALUES
  ('3', '1', '11/27/1987'),
  ('3', '1', 'test1@gmail.com'),
  ('3', '1', 'username_test'),
  ('3', '2', '11/27/1999'),
  ('3', '2', '+6582734752'),
  ('3', '2', 'Teamname1'),
  ('3', '2', 'Team1'),
  ('3', '2', 'Teamname2'),
  ('3', '2', 'Team2'),
  ('5', '3', '+862934829103'),
  ('5', '3', 'testing@test.com'),
  ('6', '4', 'Member1'),
  ('6', '4', 'Member2'),
  ('6', '4', 'Member3'),
  ('6', '4', 'Member4'),
  ('6', '4', 'TeamAlpha'),
  ('6', '4', 'teamalpha@gmail.com');
```

[DEMO at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0479c0/2)

```
SELECT
  f.form_name, s.value
FROM
  Table1 f
JOIN
  Table2 s
    ON f.form_id = s.form_id
GROUP BY
  f.form_name;
```

I hope this time round, I met the requirements of posting a question. I really need help on this as I have stuck at this stage for very long time and also my first time using join function.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: The answer in the linked question says to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to combine the values from multiple rows. Why didn't you do that?

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(s.value)`

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for pointing that out. I did include GROUP_CONCAT() before I posted this question but I don't know why it's not working too that's why I post here after a few tries getting same result. It's working now!

Comment: @Strawberry I don't understand.

Comment: Often, when interacting with a database, there's some kind of higher-level interface, like PHP, Python, C+, whatever, that's used to present the data to the end-user in a friendly manner. To my, mind, that's where you should be doing things like concatenating bits of data, and not in the query.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know if this question is a duplicate but it is not about joins. It is about UNION ALL.

Comment: @forpas He said that the linked question does what he wants. He just didn't copy what it said correctly. He's does want them joined together, he's just showing them on multiple lines for presentation.

Comment: Well i hope the OP will clarify. What I see is a section of the question starting with: *This is what I want to achieve...* If this is not the requirement then the question needs more explanation.

Comment: @Barmar the answer is accepted so I guess my first comment is valid.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys. As I have mentioned before, I am totally new to this, I thought I needed the JOIN function but it turns out that I actually need an UNION function. =S

Comment: @Strawberry I will take note on that. =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need UNION ALL and not a join, like this:

```
SELECT result
FROM (
  SELECT form_id, CONCAT('Form Name : ', form_name) result, 1 orderby, 0 submission_id 
  FROM Table1 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT form_id, CONCAT('User Details : ', GROUP_CONCAT(value)), 2, submission_id 
  FROM Table2
  GROUP BY form_id, submission_id
) t
ORDER BY form_id, orderby, submission_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e4cNMBZz517TbXu2JNLQ6W/0).
Results:

```
| result                                                                       |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Form Name : Account Registration                                             |
| User Details : test1@gmail.com,username_test,11/27/1987                      |
| User Details : Team2,Teamname2,Team1,Teamname1,+6582734752,11/27/1999        |
| Form Name : Event Registration                                               |
| User Details : +862934829103,testing@test.com                                |
| Form Name : Christmas Event Registration                                     |
| User Details : Member1,Member2,Member3,Member4,TeamAlpha,teamalpha@gmail.com |
```

Comment: OMG! Yes that's what I wanted! So all along I needed an UNION... Thanks!

Comment: But you also needed the group concat in the second query of the union.

Comment: @Barmar Yes! I guess my case needed UNION with group concat instead of JOIN with group concat.

Comment: @forpas was too tired that I k.o. wanted to ask what's the meaning of "1 orderby, 0 submission_id" and "2, submission_id" that you used in the query?

Comment: These are columns used to sort the result, so each form name is sorted first and below it its user details.

Comment: @forpas I see. Based on your query, is there a way to beautify the result? Say I want to present it in tr td, like every form will have its own table. Or should I post as a new question?

Comment: I can't help you with html. So you need to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try Group_Concat and another group by
like

```
SELECT
  f.form_name, GROUP_CONCAT(s.value)
FROM
  Table1 f
JOIN
  Table2 s
    ON f.form_id = s.form_id
GROUP BY
  s.form_id,s.submission_id,f.form_name;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0479c0/14

Edit: This works also with full group by

Comment: What is the difference between the GROUP BY I've used and yours?

Comment: The form id 3  has 2 different submission_ids, so it produces two rows, yours would list all the values in one row for 'Account Registration' . But you can add a second query after mine in the link without the submission_id to see both results